# Very simple .rmd --> beamer_presentation; still cannot get rid of "Option clash for package xcolor"

Tags: r, latex, knitr, beamer

I cannot compile to a pdf-beamer from a very simple minimal example (below), with *no* packages.

I click - Knit - Knit to pdf

(Note this is not a duplicate of previous posts, because those all involved using Kable; I am not using it; fresh restart not calling any packages here)

I tried with and without `classoption: table`

Knit to html works just fine.

Restarted Rstudio; no improvement

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Test"
date: "20 novembre 2018"
classoption: table
output:
  beamer_presentation:
      keep_tex: yes
---


# Test nothing 

blah  
```
````

Throws error: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`

I want it to compile a beamer pdf slide show, of course.

I've put the log file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fgshq4l00qxkgd/testerror.log?dl=0)

My default.beamer (stored at /Users/yosemite/.pandoc/templates/default.beamer I think) is linked [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbn2vl7s0xoxksw/default.beamer?dl=0)

Comment: can you test with `classoption: xcolor={table}` ?

Comment: Can you intercept the .tex file which is created during the creation of the pdf?

Comment: @samcarter Swapping in `classoption: xcolor={table}`  yields another error:  `Argument of \@font@info has an extra }.`

Comment: Yes I can intercept the tex file; it just occurs to me that me pandoc template must be including a bunch of packages, including `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`
This may be the source of the problem. Now I just need to remember where that pandoc template is stored.

Comment: I found my template but I don't see where/why it is adding the [dvipsnames]{xcolor} ... that is commented out. 

Should I post the tex output &/or the beamer pandoc template file here?

Comment: Yes, please do post both. I cannot promise anything (I'm not familiar with pandoc templates), but maybe something stands out.

Comment: @samcarter by the way, I've posted the [log file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fgshq4l00qxkgd/testerror.log?dl=0) and my [default.beamer here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbn2vl7s0xoxksw/default.beamer?dl=0)